# Core data and n number of entity "Person"

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

can i have an entity have a to-many relationship to itself?

getting a group list from my server, and it can have n number of names and n number of levels. at the top level, lets say i have:

```
Scott
Jason
```

Scott and Jason both have n number of employees under them. Scott has

```
Bryan
Matt
```

Bryan and Matt both have n number of employees under them

```
Jill
Lisa
```

Jill and Lisa both have n Number of employees under them.

sortive like:

[image]

but with n subGroups.

my list can have n levels. it needs to be dynamic.

can i boil it down to:

[image]

can i just have one entity, Person, that has many-to-many relationship to itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an entity can have a many-to-many relationship to itself. You have to define two to-many relationships, e.g.

- `members` as to-many relationship from `Person` to `Person`,
- `leaders` as to-many relationship from `Person` to `Person`,

and set both as inverse relationships of each other.

[image]

See also [Many-to-Many Relationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW10) in the "Core Data Programming Guide".

Comment: Ok, and this would support n number levels like i described? I'm not that experienced with databases and core data.

Comment: @Log139: Core Data manages an *object graph*, a set of objects with relations between them, so in view of Core Data, there are no levels (that is only your interpretation). In this case for example, Core Data would store one table with all person objects, and another table with all the relationships between the persons. (But the actual implementation should normally not matter.) - So if I understand your requirements correctly, this should be possible.

Comment: yes, i use the term "levels" abstractly and loosely. i'll give a try, thanks!